# missing : after property id - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have what I thought was a simple function but I can't figure out what I'm missing here. There error I'm getting is `missing : after property id` and it references:

```
var data = { "'" + $(this).attr('id') + "'" : "'" + $(this).val() + "'" };
```

Here's the function:

```
function ArrayPush($group) {
    var arr = new Array();
    $group.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {
        var data = { "'" + $(this).attr('id') + "'" : "'" + $(this).val() + "'" };
        arr.push(data);
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I like how 4 people just answered the same thing within seconds of each other

Comment: Totally unrelated: Why not `this.id`?

Comment: Perhaps those duplicate answers' owners could delete their questions? I suspect the OP gets the point loud and clear.

Comment: A property name in an object literal can be a string literal, but cannot be an expression that returns a string literal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ArrayPush($group) {
    var arr = new Array();
    $group.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {
        arr[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: this answer is wrong - it's setting the _named_ properties of an _array_, not pushing objects into the array's _numbered_ indices (per the OP's original code) nor adding keys to an _object_, which would be the more normal result.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` == `this.id` && `$(this).val()` == `this.value`, however not using the jQuery functions is faster. Some attributes like `href` are nice to get through jQuery (because it will be normalized to the base-url of the page.

Comment: @Jasper AFAIK `href` depends on whether you're obtaining the _attribute_, or the _property_ and it's not jQuery that does the normalisation.

Comment: @Alnitak `document.getElementById('some-link-id').href` gets the property, which will be the complete URL. `document.getElementById('some-link-id').getAttribute('href')` gets the attribute, which will be the actual value of the `href` attribute on the element. Are these statements correct? Thanks.

Comment: -1 For just pasting some code without any decent explanation.

Comment: @Jasper yes, that's correct - the property will be normalised, and the attribute will have the value as specified in the markup.

Answer (score 9):

You can't create an object like that - the "key" in an object literal must be a constant, not a variable or expression.

If the key is a variable you need the array-like syntax instead:

```
myArray[key] = value;
```

Hence you need:

```
var data = {};  // empty object
data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
```

However as all of your fields are actually plain `HTMLInputElement` or `HTMLTextAreaElement` objects, you should really use this and avoid those expensive jQuery calls:

```
var data = {};  // empty object
data[this.id] = this.value;
```

I'd also question why you're creating an *array of objects* - as the keys should all be unique, I would normally expect to return a single object:

```
function formObjectBuild($group) {
    var obj = {};
    $group.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {
        obj[this.id] = this.value;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't build property names dynamically like that.

```
function ArrayPush($group) {
    var arr = new Array();
    $group.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {
        var data = {};
        data [$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        arr.push(data);
    });
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Arrays should almost always be made with the literal syntax `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {};
data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
```

Use that instead. Otherwise you're trying to do some kind of eval...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing that to.

```
var data = {};
data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
```